# '' is not a valid floating point value

Tags: sql

I'm working with A5:SQL MK-2.

I'm trying to import csv file with two data:

```
"MMC",19990101,"*"
"MMC",19990102,"*"
```

But I can not do it. I get this error:

> '' is not a valid floating point value.

My table in the database contains:

```
+ column A datatype: VARCHAR(4)
+ column B datatype: DECIMAL(8,0)
+ column C datatype: VARCHAR(1)
```

Comment: Are you sure the `,` is the right separator? Are you sure varchar values can be quoted? And (never having heard of A5:SQL before) you may need to explain *how* you tried importing this CSV

Comment: A5:SQL seems to be a [SQL _client_](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/a5-sql-mk-2-x64/9nsbb9xtjw86?activetab=pivot:overviewtab) that can connect to many different database system. Which DBMS product are you connecting to?

Comment: Yes, I'm working with japanese, they use A5, It like MYSQL, MICROSOFTSQ, ORACLE.

Comment: I'm use datagrid jetbrain to import the same csv file , it's ok but A5 is not ok with column hava data type DECIMAL